# Debugging native library: breakpoint is hit in C++, but "Step ..." commands unavailable

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm using the default "app-native" debug configuration. I simply select it, click "Debug", the app starts and the native breakpoint gets hit soon enough:

[image]

However, I cannot step anywhere. It's as if the IDE does not recognize that debugging is already in progress and the execution is halted. As you can see, all the step over / step into and similar actions are unavailable:

[image]

Pressing Pause does nothing.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

NDK features are already experimental, but it seems a weird error.

Maybe you have than this steps but, just in case:

- Define your as lldb the debugger.
- Define your NDK in the path that
  you downloaded (NDK11c should be enough)
- Use gradle experimental 0.4.0 or 0.7.0 on android root build.gradle project.
- Define your ndk module node in app/build.gradle.

gradle experimental:

```
dependencies 
{
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
}

//android ndk-module 
    android.ndk {
                moduleName = "sensorgraph"
                cppFlags.add("-Werror")
            }
```

If you try default debug with android studio native examples, the problem should be in LLDB debugger.

Cheers.

Comment: Might be of note that I'm not using a 100% Gradle project, only wrapper over my old style Android.mk / Application.mk projects.

And it doesn't compile with 0.4.0 nor 0.7.0. Says it needs 1.1.0+.

Comment: sorry, but I never used android.mk-s on android studio, only in eclipse, but as far as I know if you want to use ndk compilation, you should define ndk module in your gradle files and define gradle experimental if you want to debug the app. try to exec android studio ndk samples. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk